# Some respondents put birth year not age, need to convert it all to age (in R)

Tags: r, converters

I have a survey and one of the questions asked for age (years). Most people put their ages, but some have put their birth year. So I need to convert those into age (2020-year). Is there a way to do this that doesn't mean manually going through each year and converting it? I'm using R. 
Also, so the code is usable in the future, is there a way to count from the 'current' year, rather than 2020?

```
age<-c(22,1992,18,33,41,26,24,24,1982,30,1976,30)
```

This will teach me for the next survey to put a 'max' into the value box!

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi there, can you please post a reproducible example (you can use `dput()`) and expected output? Thanks

Comment: try to put logic like this into a data.table (or data.frame) statement: if age > 1000, age = 2020 - age

Comment: Something like `DF[DF$age > 100, "age"] <- 2020 - DF[DF$age > 100, "age"]`?

Comment: @sotos really sorry, I'm not sure I know how to do that? I could give an example of my code? 

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  18.00   23.00   27.00   30.57   32.00 1996.00      20 

   [1]   47   20   28   27   40   31   23   33   33   19   32   42   25   26   22   34   45
  [18]   21   40   40   27   25   25   26   39   23   26   26   25   31   26   23   32   39
  [35]   29   24   20   27   27   27   25   31   28   32   29   29   26   18   22   29   33

Comment: Here you go: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by using a simple `ifelse`statement along these lines:

if `age` is > `1000`, substract `age` from the current year `2020`; if `age` is not > `1000`, keep `age`:

```
ifelse(age > 1000, 2020 - age, age)
[1] 22 28 18 33 41 26 24 24 38 30 44 30
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to get the other way around, so age from year of birth-sorry I wasn't clear!
survey <-survey %>%
  ifelse(age>99, 2020-age,age)

But this doesn't work

Comment: A little confused: you want ages, right? Something like 22, 32, etc.?